# How can I fill up and fill up the missing values of each group in Dataframe using Python?

Tags: python, group-by

This is an example of the dataframe:

For example,

```
df = 

     Name         Type               Price 

0    gg         apartment            8   
1    hh         apartment            4
2    tty        apartment            0
3    ttyt       None                 6
4    re         house                6 
5    ew         house                2
6    rr         house                0
7    tr         None                 5
8    mm         None                 0
```

I worked on converting the "unknown" to "NoInfo" in "Type":

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import zscore

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/properties.csv")

df.Type.fillna(value=pd.np.nan, inplace=True)

df['Type'].fillna(value='NoInfo', inplace = True)

The dataframe is like below:

For example,

```
df = 
     Name         Type               price 

0    gg         apartment            8   
1    hh         apartment            4
2    tty        apartment            0
3    ttyt       NoInfo               6
4    re         house                6 
5    ew         house                2
6    rr         house                0
7    tr         NoInfo               5
8    mm         NoInfo               0
```

After that, I replaced the "0" values to the average value of the prices of each group "Apartment", "House" and "NoInfo" and take the z-score of each group.

df['price'] = df['price'].replace(0, np.nan)

df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df.price, errors='coerce')

df['price'] = df.groupby('Type')['price'].transform(lambda x : x.mean())

df['price_zscore'] = df[['price']].apply(zscore)

After running this code, all values of the prices of all property groups have been changed and all z-score values in independent variable 'price_zscore' are "NaN".

I am looking to get the average value of the price for each property group "Apartments and houses" in "Type" with replacing '0' in independent variable 'price' with the average of each property group (apartments, houses).

For example, the "0" values in independent variable "price" in the property group "Apartment" in independent variable "Type" has to be replaced with the average of prices the property group "Apartment", the "0" values in "price" in property group "house" has to be replaced with the average of prices the property group "house" and the "0" values in "price" in property group "NoInfo" has to be replaced with the average of prices the property group "NoInfo"

df = 
         Name         Type               Price

```
0    gg         apartment            8   
1    hh         apartment            4
2    tty        apartment            6   # (8+4)/2 = 6
3    ttyt       NoInfo               6
4    re         house                6 
5    ew         house                2
6    rr         house                4  # (6+2)/2 = 4
7    tr         NoInfo               5
8    mm         NoInfo               0
```

After that, I am looking to get the "Z-score" of each property group. For example, I am looking to get the z-score of the property group "Apartment", the Zscore of the property group "House" and the zscore of the "NoInfo" group and put all z-scores of all groups in independent varieble 'price_zscore'.

I need really your help to fix the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pandas` you can replace missing values with NaN using `replace()`. Then you can impute them with the group mean. Eventually, you can compute the z-score of the price using the function `zscore` from the `stats` module of `scipy`.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import zscore


df = pd.read_csv('./data.csv')

df['price'] = df['price'].replace(0, np.nan)
df['price'] = df.groupby('type').transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))

df['price_zscore'] = df[['price']].apply(zscore) # You need to apply score function on a DataFrame—not a Series.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I did what you advised me to do as following

Comment: new_df = df.replace(['Unknown', 'na'], np.nan)

df["price"] = df.groupby("Type").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))

but I got this error:
Transform function invalid for data types

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I understand from your code that you filled up all fields "0" in independent features area with the average value of all prices of all properties "Apartments and houses".

Comment: My question was how can I get the average value of each property "Apartments and houses" in "Type" and replace '0' in independent variable 'price' with the average of each property group.

Comment: For example, the "0" values in "price" in property group "Apartment" has to be replaced with the average of prices the property group "Apartment" and the "0" values in "price" in property group "house" has to be replaced with the average of prices the property group "house".

Comment: with ignoring "NoInfo" independent variable "Type" (this is not necessary to get the average price of "NoInfo" in "Type")

Comment: I write this part of code, I would like to review it 
and fix it if there is a mistake: 

df['price'] = df.price.apply(lambda x: x if x>0 else pd.np.nan)

m = df.groupby('Type').mean().price

df['price'] = df.apply(lambda row: m[row['Type']] if pd.isnull(row['price']) else row['price'],axis=1) 

I need your help

Comment: After that, I am looking to compute the z-score of the independent variable "price". I write the code below, but I have received an error "Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4906 elements, new values have 4910 elements "Do you have any idea how can I fix this error:

    name = ['price']

    price_zscore = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()

    df[name] = df.groupby([df.Type])[name].transform(price_zscore)

Thanks a lot

Comment: @Elwakdy sorry for the heavy lifting... but all your precisions are now incorporated :)

Comment: Thank you so much, Leoburgy for your great help. I follow the steps of your code, but I all prices in the independent variable "price" have been changed as independent variable 'price_zscore' has NaN values. I made some changes the question to review and help me to fix the code.